# Trying to Figure Out how to work with datasets & Classify[] and Predict[]

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm new to Mathematica and I'm a bit overwhelmed. I have always used R for my statistics problems. Now that I'm trying to replicate what I do in R in Mathematica I'm making little progress.

For instance: Something as basic as reading a csv file and running a regression is giving me trouble.

Let me ask a simple question. Suppose I have a csv file with 4 columns: "beer", "income", "gender", "age".

R:

```
beer <- read.csv("beer.csv")
reg1 <- lm( beer~income+gender+age,data=beer)
```

Mathematica:

```
beer <- Import["beer.csv"]
reg1 <- Predict[   ]  ?????
```

I don't know how to refer to the different variables. Help is not very helpful because it only contains very simple examples that can be entered one by one.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just want to report a final variation on Albert's answer. I just installed version 10.0.2 and this version lets you simplify things a little. The final answer would be:

```
beerdata =   SemanticImport["https://s3.amazonaws.com/mirlitus/datos/beer.csv"];
Model1 = Predict[beerdata[All,{"beer","income","age","gender","education"}]->"beer"]
```

Notice that if I hadn't had to drop "id" the last line would be even simpler

```
Model1 = Predict[beerdata->"beer"]
```

Comment: If you are the original poster, but just didn't fully register the first time [this link might be helpful](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). If you merge your accounts, the rep you gained from the question will be added to that earned from the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. A few hours later I have succeeded at making it work. It's not the most elegant code but it works. Here it goes:

```
beer=Import["https://s3.amazonaws.com/mirlitus/datos/beer.csv"];
```

Names of the variables are in the first row:

```
beer[[1]]
```

First column is an ID variable. Second column is the dependent variable. There are 40 rows.

```
independent = beer[[2 ;;, {3, 4, 5, 6}]];
dependent = beer[[2 ;;, {2}]]
data = Flatten[Table[{independent[[i]] -> dependent[[i]][[1]]}, {i, 1, 40}], 1]
```

And now use the function **Predict**

```
Model1 = Predict[datos, Method -> "LinearRegression"]
```

Ugly... but it works :-)

I suspect that the line about defining "data" can be obtained more elegantly. If anybody can comment I would appreaciate it. I'm still learning.

Comment: something like this? 
`beer =.; {id, beer, income, age, gender, education} = 
 Map[Rest,Transpose[Import["https://s3.amazonaws.com/mirlitus/datos/beer.csv"]]];
Model1 = Predict[MapThread[Rule, {beer, age}], Method -> "LinearRegression"]`

Comment: Or, making use of the new v10 functionalities (which will work surprisingly well for this example): `beerdata = 
 SemanticImport["https://s3.amazonaws.com/mirlitus/datos/beer.csv"]` and then: `data = ({"income", "age", "gender", "education"} -> "beer") /. Normal[beerdata]`

Comment: Beautiful. That's exactly what I meant. Thank you Chris. But I think we need all the variables in the last line: MapThread[Rule,{Transpose[{income,age,gender,education}],beer}];

Comment: Albert: Thank you very much to you too. Your answer is both elegant and simple. Really close to what you can do in R.